How do we know that the number of points on a line is uncountable?
The question is simple one, how do we know that there is a bijection between the points in a line and an uncountable set (such as the power set of natural numbers)? Why don’t countably infinite sets that are dense (such as the rational numbers) correspond 1-1 with all the points on a line? The simplest possible explanation that assumes minimal background knowledge of the inquirer would be greatly appreciated.
-Thank you

Do you know why the set of real numbers is uncountable?

@ThomasAndrews Yes, it is because it contains more elements than can be corresponded to by the set of natural numbers, this is shown by Cantor’s diagonal  argument.

Without essentially knowing the line is in one-to-one correspondence with the real numbers, you actually can't show the line is uncountable. Euclid's postulates hve a model with a countable line, and a countable plane.

@ThomasAndrews That makes perfect sense, so it’s a matter of definition based on one’s model.

I mean, there exist rather simple models of plane geometry - for example, the set of pairs of points $(x,y)$ with $x,y$ algebraic numbers satisfies Euclid's postulates.

But to prove it, you have to define geometry in set theory. There is no such thing as the functions, the natural numbers, etc in formal geometry.

This is due to Cantor–Dedekind axiom. In rigorous formulations of Euclidean Geometry, this statement is taken as an axiom or is a theorem. This statement is actually independent of Euclid's original axioms and is assumed implicitly in Elements.

Thank you for the response! Regarding it being a theorem, seeing that it is independent from Euclid’s axioms, under which systems can it be derived as a theorem?

its a theorem in rigorous formulations of Euclidean Geometry (eg. Hilbert, Artin etc). In Euclid's original work, with appropriate interpretation, there are models which don't satisfy this statement.

Lucid and concise, bless your soul. Thank you so much!

@MaxMaxman if you are interested, read books by George Martin or Borsuk on Foundations of Geometry

I’ll definitely check it out, thanks for the recommendation.

I think this answer still misses one piece of the story. The Cantor-Dedekind axiom is indeed a theorem of Euclidean geometry if you add a still simpler axiom added. In the last edition of Hilbert's Grundlugen this was the axiom of line completeness.

@LeeMosher yes, you are right.

@LeeMosher Thank you for the additional input. With that being said, Ajin Shaji Jose can you point me towards any systems that don’t essentially adhere to Cantor–Dedekind axiom (aside from Euclid’s original system)?

@MaxMaxman i am not aware of any Euclidean Geometry axiom system that have negation of Cantor-Dedekind as its consequence. However, I know of a model of plane that satisfies Euclid's axioms but not Cantor-Dedekind. Consider all ordered pair of algebraic numbers and we can define other stuff similar to standard Cartesian plane
